# DIV not scrolled on mobile devices

Tags: html, scroll

im my site wont scroll left or right on mobile devices,
tried looking for an answer but all i found didnt help

the site adress is www.muchmarketing.co.il (sorry for the foreign language :) )
anyway , i tried wrapping up the entire site with a div giving it relative position but it didnt help as well

Any thoughts on how to solve that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />` from your HTML.